# Azure blob storage multiple simultaneous uploads with progress

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload multiple files simultaneously to Azure BLOB storage from JavaScript. I'm not sure how it's handling the parallelism, but I'm trying to have separate progress bars for each file/upload/promise.

Now the progress function gets called but gives only "loadedBytes" I need a way to know which progress bar to update.. One person suggested onload give an identifier, it does not seem to have an onload event. When I use the code below, the index is always the last one in the loop.

```
   try {
        console.log("Uploading files…");
        var inputElement = document.getElementById('fileSelector');

        const promises = [];
        
        for (var fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < inputElement.files.length; fileIndex++) {
            const file = inputElement.files[fileIndex];
            var thisToken = await this.Instance.invokeMethodAsync('jsGetSASToken', file.name);
            var containerURL = new azblob.ContainerURL(thisToken, azblob.StorageURL.newPipeline(new azblob.AnonymousCredential));
            const blockBlobURL = azblob.BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, file.name);
            
            var blobUploadOptions = {
                blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
                parallelism: 20, // 20 concurrency
                metadata: { 'testindex': fileIndex.toString() },                    
                progress: function (ev) {
                    var percentdone = ((ev.loadedBytes / file.size) * 100);

                    // Jumps around because loadedBytes is different for each upload
                    document.getElementById('percentdone-' + fileIndex).innerHTML = percentdone.toFixed(2) + "%";

                    // fileIndex is always the last item in the loop                        
                }
                
            };

            promises.push(
                azblob.uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(
                    azblob.Aborter.none,
                    file,
                    blockBlobURL,
                    blobUploadOptions
                )
            );
        }

        await Promise.all(promises);            
        console.log('Done.');           
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("File Upload Error");
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @TimDavis, may I know how's going now? If my answer is helpful, could you please accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this issue is caused by `fileIndex`. I use `file.name` as the identifier, everything works as excepted. Try the code below:

```
<html>

<body>

    <button id="select-button">Select and upload files</button>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" multiple style="display: none;" />
    <div id="showProgress"></div>


    <p><b>Status:</b></p>
    <p id="status" style="height:160px; width: 593px; overflow: scroll;" />

    
</body>
<script src="./azure-storage-blob.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

const selectButton = document.getElementById("select-button");
const fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");
const status = document.getElementById("status");

const reportStatus = message => {
    status.innerHTML += `${message}<br/>`;
    status.scrollTop = status.scrollHeight;
}

const accountName = "storage account";
const sasString = "sas token";
const containerName = "container";

const containerURL = new azblob.ContainerURL(
    `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}?${sasString}`,
    azblob.StorageURL.newPipeline(new azblob.AnonymousCredential));

const uploadFiles = async () => {
    try {
        reportStatus("Uploading files...");
        const promises = [];
        for (var fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < fileInput.files.length; fileIndex++) {
            const file = fileInput.files[fileIndex];
            const blockBlobURL = azblob.BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, file.name);

            document.getElementById('showProgress').innerHTML += file.name +":<div id='progress-"+ file.name +"'></div>"
            

            var blobUploadOptions = {
                blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
                parallelism: 20, // 20 concurrency
                metadata: { 'testindex': fileIndex.toString() },                    
                progress: function (ev) {
                    var percentdone = ((ev.loadedBytes / file.size) * 100);
                    var progessItem = document.getElementById('progress-' + file.name);
                    progessItem.innerHTML = percentdone.toFixed(2) + "%";                     
                }
            };
            var promise = azblob.uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(
                azblob.Aborter.none, file, blockBlobURL,blobUploadOptions);
            
            promise.then((result)=>{
                var progessItem = document.getElementById('progress-' + file.name);
                progessItem.innerHTML += "  <a href="+result._response.request.url+">file link</a>" 
                
            });

            promises.push(promise);
        }
        await Promise.all(promises);

        reportStatus("Done.");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

selectButton.addEventListener("click", () => fileInput.click());
fileInput.addEventListener("change", uploadFiles);


</script>

</html>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

**Update Result:**
[image]

Comment: This answer is helpful I have not had time to try it yet but I believe it will work.. bonus.. can we get the filename or the index of the promise that's completed?

Comment: @TimDavis, thanks for the reply. I have updated my answer with the code to get the storage file link from promises by then() function. And if my post is helpful, could you please accept it? I will be glad to answer your next questions